# Advanced installer - dealing with svn conflicts

Tags: svn, advanced-installer

I am trying to find out what is the best way of dealing with conflicts in advanced installer projects.

**Problem:** If I modify even single field (e.g. Install Condition for IIS web site) after saving project I see that almost whole file changed and these changes are way too confusing (some entries reordered/removed or just slightly modified e.g. just NextFile property changed).

I have few options:

1. Documenting all steps in UI required to perform the change and commit confusing changes in installer (and then when merging just change things from in UI)
2. After changing installer from UI revert all confusing changes and leave only those changes which reflect what I actually changed through UI (e.g. if I changed just Condition in UI then ONLY that condition should be changed in XML)

2) sounds better to me as I'd like to have clear history in SVN, however sometimes it will be very difficult to find out what is required and what should be reverted.

Ideally I'd like advanced installer to change only that what I have changed. If that is not possible can anyone please explain me what is the right process of dealing with advanced installer changes across multiple branches?

(Advanced Installer 10.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on our forums, [merging is not supported for Advanced Installer projects](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21914). You should mark these projects as binary files and manually apply the changes on each branch.

Regarding the changes you mentioned, that should not happen when you simply edit a condition or add/delete a file. Usually big changes appear in the project when you upgrade from one version of AI to another, and even then it is not always changing that much.

Can you send us a project sample on support at advanced installer dot com and tell us what change you are implementing, to see if AI is changing something it should not.

Also, version 10.3 is [very old](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/version-history.html), you might consider upgrading.

Comment: Thank you for answer and offer to investigate our installer, however I am not in a position to send this installer - we will just go with 1st option that I mentioned.